# apply different term sets to top navigation and quick launch

Tags: quick-launch, term-store, top-link-bar

I used Managed metadata Navigation to display links on my top navigation. That is fine, but I would like to display a different set of links in the quick launch. When I enable both options in Site Settings\Navigation, I get to see the same links in the top navigation and in the quick launch.

Is it possible to use a different set of terms for Quick launch? These links should be different from the top menu. 
If it is not possible to use a term set, can you tell me how can I bind the quick launch to a custom list so that I can get the data from there?

Answer (score 1):

In terms store you can choose to display in Global or Current Navigation. 
Select your term and then select Navigation tab, in "Visibility In Menus" section.

If you check "Show In Global Navigation" then term will appear in top navigation.

If you check "Show In Current Navigation" then term will appear in current (side bar) navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the GUI I am afraid they can not use different term set, you would have to write a custom control for either of the navigations (which is the simpler one is really based on your needs from each navigation)

Basically you would need to open a TaxonomSession and locate the correct TermGroup and TermSet, and the iterate over terms (and terms subterms and so on) to render the nodes. You can use the Taxonomy classes starting with Navigation (NavigationTermSet etc) to find the url:s (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.navigationtermset.aspx)

Comment: A UserControl with a code bind that executes code, or that uses the client object model. I'm not aware of any no code solution